# Append json data to already existing json data

Tags: java, json

I have a json string like this

```
{
  "bitrate": false,
  "bitrateInit": 40000,
  "bitr": 10000
}
```

I have to append following data to this

```
 "test": {"enable":true }
```

final data will be

```
{
  "bitrate": false,
  "bitrateInit": 40000,
  "bitr": 10000,
   "test": {"enable":true }
}
```

How can i perform it with java

```
String str= "{"bitrate":false,"bitrateInit":40000,"bitr":10000}";

 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(str);
```

How can i append  this 'str' value to alreday existing josn object

Comment: Parse it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
        String str= "{\"bitrate\":false,\"bitrateInit\":40000,\"bitr\":10000}";
        String str2= "{\"enable\":true }";

        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(str);
        jObj.put("test", new JSONObject(str2));
        System.out.println(jObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse your json string and convert it to JSONobject first.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
```

Now create and put `test` json object inside it using `put()`.

```
JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
test.put("enable", true);
jsonObj.put("test", test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two model class and then put it to a map. Example is below:

**Model1.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Model1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean bitrate;

    private int bitrateInit;

    private int bitr;

    private Test test;

    public boolean isBitrate() {
        return bitrate;
    }

    public void setBitrate(boolean bitrate) {
        this.bitrate = bitrate;
    }

    public int getBitrateInit() {
        return bitrateInit;
    }

    public void setBitrateInit(int bitrateInit) {
        this.bitrateInit = bitrateInit;
    }

    public int getBitr() {
        return bitr;
    }

    public void setBitr(int bitr) {
        this.bitr = bitr;
    }

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean enable;

    public boolean isEnable() {
        return enable;
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

}
```

**RequestController.java**

```
@RestController
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL + "getAllData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public HashMap<String, Object> getAllData () {

        HashMap<String, Object> plr = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Test t = new Test();
        t.setEnable(true);
        Model1 model1 = new Model1();
        model1.setBitrate(true);
        model1.setBitrateInit(180000);
        model1.setBitr(1400);
        model1.setTest(t);

        plr.put("data", model1);

        return plr;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "bitrate": true,
    "bitrateInit": 180000,
    "bitr": 1400,
    "test": {
      "enable": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
obj = {
   "bitr": 10000,
   "bitrate": false,
   "bitrateInit": 40000
};

var newVar = "test";
var newVal = {"enable":true };

obj[newVar] = newVal;

console.log(obj);

//Result will be
{
   "bitr": 10000,
   "bitrate": false,
   "bitrateInit": 40000,
   "test": {"enable":true }
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanations!

Comment: Wrong language.